# Repository / services pattern and data consistency

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, oop, repository-pattern

**In a application that use Repositories and Services pattern, how to make sure Service layer is always called and not the Repositories directly ?**

Example :

```
class OrderRepository
{
    void CreateOrder(Order o)
    ...
}

class OrderService
{
    void CreateOrder(Order o)
    {
        //make some business logic tests
        ... 

        //call repository
        _orderRepository.CreateOrder(o);
    }
}
```

I see two issues :

- A programmer may call the repository directly because it doesn't know the existance of a service (sometimes its not as simple as in this example (1 service = 1 repository with same method names). some applications are not very well documented. or someone in hurry can forget to check if corresponding service exists (mistake)).
- Totally different : long time ago someone created some views + controllers that use order repository directly. At that time there was no need to have some business logic check or additional operations, only order repository exists (because there it was not needed at all). If later, some additional operations when creating an order would be needed, a service will be created. the problem is that all controllers that make old repositories calls will need to be changed. Isn't repository principle/idea (and separating code in layers) supposed to make parts independent from each other ?

Comment: "...supposed to make parts independent from each other?" This is a misinterpretation. It is meant to make *responsibilities* independent of each other. `OrderRepository` remains responsible for fetching data from and saving data to database, and `OrderService` for applying the logic of managing orders. Try to make these responsibilities clearer by improving the method names. `SaveOrder` instead of `CreateOrder` for `OrderRepository` is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  structure your solution so that all repositories and services are in their own respective projects, ex. `Repositories` and `Services`.

The only project that should reference `Repositories` would be `Services`. This way, other projects wouldn't have access to the repositories. Of course, nothing is to stop a developer from including the repositories project to the controllers project, but hopefully at this point they'll be asking themselves why it wasn't included in the first place.

Comment: in other words : does it means i would have to create a service for every possible repository from the beginning (and for every method inside) ? if i have a lot of repositories and methods would it need a huge effort to create initially and maintain ? (or maybe i don't understand your proposition)

Comment: It's possible I didn't understand your question. What I'm describing is if repositories are never called directly, so yes, there is always a service that will call one (or more) repositories. If some repositories could be called directly than this won't work. As for effort, there is a bit more plumbing involved if you just want to expose a simple repository method, but I find it worth it.

Answer (score 1):

[Static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools can help in this respect.

[nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is a commercial tool that can be integrated into your build process and error on such a condition (any non service class calling a repository class directly).